# Writing a script for automatic input method switching

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard-layout, ibus

I use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and want to write a bash script for Vim *(it's just: output 1 if the current language is English and 2 if Russian, that simple)*. I don't ask you to write it for me, I just need guidance.

Using `im-config` I've selected `ibus` as the input method manager *(Supposedly GNOME uses it by default)*. In *Settings > Keyboard*, I selected the desired 2 languages:
[image: GNOME settings setup]

But I also can set up those 2 languages using `ibus-setup` *(I have nothing here, yet)*

[image: Ibus preferences setup]

**Now the issue:** if I check my input method with `ibus engine` - it's always `xkb:us::eng` and there is no `xkb:ru::rus` *(even though with GNOME's approach my language switches inside the terminal without any trouble)*. How should I resolve this? Why are there 2 GUI apps for managing input methods if GNOME uses IBus by default?

P.S. I switch my languages with `CapsLock` by using Gnome-Tweaks *(So I still want to be able to use `CapsLock` to switch languages)*

Comment: Does this `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/mru-sources | awk -F"[][)(',]" '{print $7}'` work for you?

Comment: This reads contents of the `/org/gnome/desktop/input-souces/mru-sources` inside the `dconf` databse (similar to `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`). Then the output is parsed by `awk` (can't comprehend what really happens there) to get `us` or `ru` (though idk why the 7th argument of the script is printed out), am I right?. 
P.S. Is there a manual about GNOME's input method manager? Because I additionally want to write an executable for changing my input method and currently I don't know what is the GNOME's command for changing the input method inisde the terminal.

Comment: It's not "7th argument" but rather 7th field in the output string split around the values of the field separators in `-F"[][)(',]"` ... and yes it reads the value of the **m**ost **r**ecently **u**sed sources `mru-sources` key ... I ran `dbus-monitor` while switching layouts and noticed that key value getting changed and it looked consistent enough for me to suggest it as a solution ... I haven't tried it on more than two layouts though, but it should work as well ... Since the display server got merged into user sessions after Wayland, things got a bit complicated in Gnome I think.

Comment: Can I use `ibus` itself instead of whatever Ubuntu has as the default?
**If not** - will switching to Debian let me actually set up that thing on my own?